# What is not equal to in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, conditional-statements, equals

I am using conditions in Laravel. How should I use not equal to in below condition?

```
$conditions = ['player_id' => auth()->id(), 'is_confirmed' => 'pending', 'user_id' <>  auth()->id()];
```

**Edit:**

In addition, how could I use `or clause` in this condition like this:

```
$conditions = ['player_id' => auth()->id(), 'is_confirmed' => 'pending', 'user_id' <>  auth()->id(), or 'is_deleted' => false];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write as below:

```
$conditions = [
    ['player_id', auth()->id()],
    ['is_confirmed', 'pending'],
    ['user_id', '<>', auth()->id()]
];
```